# Clausal form for Disjoint sets

Tags: database, set

How to mention two disjoint sets A(x,y) and B(x,y) in clausal form? I am able to write the clausal forms of FDs and other constraints.But I am unable to do this.Can anybody help?

Comment: Your problem description is too verbose. A much more succinct (and, therefore, easier to understand) question would be: "Disjo..t A(x,y) B, cl..al form, h..p"

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it just {{A(x,y)},{B(x,y)}}?

A and B are predicates, is x and y a constant (usually small letter) or a variable (usually capital letter) ?